# What happened to the icons in my tray area?

Tags: gnome-panel, icons

After I installed Ubuntu, I removed the top panel where all of the notifications and applet are since I was used to Windows. Can anyone tell me how to get all of those tray icons like the Internet icon on my lower screen bar back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the panel and click 'Add to panel', now search 'indicator applet', 'clock', 'notification area', 'main menu'... and click 'add' or drag and drop each one of them to the panel.

Comment: thank you.suppose i had deleted my botom bar,where i see all the minimized windows,how can i make these minimized windows appear on the top bar?

Comment: do the same as mentioned before: right click on panel and click 'Add to panel', now search "window list". You can place it by clicking add or doing the drag and drop.